Restrict the number of non-zero variables to any constant in MILP
I am designing an MILP in which given a set $[n]$ of $n$ agents, we create for each $i \in [n]$ a real variable $x_i$. The variables $x_i$ are between 0 and 1 ($0 \leq x_i < 1$).
I would like to restrict the number of times $x_i = 0$ to any integer constant $m$.
Is there any way to do this using some linear constraints?

Define binary variable $y_i$ for each $i$. Let $\epsilon$ be a small constant close to $0$. You can enforce the desired constraints by adding the following:
\begin{align}
\epsilon y_i \le x_i &\le y_i \quad \forall i \tag{1}\\
\sum_i (1-y_i) &\le m \tag{2}
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ enforce $y_i = 0 \implies x_i = 0$ and $y_i=1 \implies x_i\ge \epsilon >0$. Constraints $(2)$ impose that the number of times $y_i=0$ (and thus $x_i$) is smaller than $m$.

What if there is a solution in which $x_i < \epsilon$?

If there is an optimal solution to the original problem with $x_i < \epsilon,$ you won't find it, and will end up with a suboptimal solution. This is essentially the price of doing business, because (for a variety of reasons) optimization models do not tolerate strict inequality constraints.

So the answer to my initial question is "no"?

I would not say that. What does $x_i$ represent exactly ? If you set for example $\epsilon = 10^{-6}$, what are you missing (in terms of $x_i$)?

@SamuelBismuth, let me turn it back to you -- can you give an example where it matters, i.e., where the best solution returned by this heuristic differs substantially from the optimal solution to your original system of constraints?

@D.W., I did not think about such an example, but it is difficult to prove the contrary (that there is no case where the best solution differs from the optimal solution).
